# FancyTree bootstrap theme doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, fancytree

I have my FancyTree initialised in a class. Here's what the class imports:
**Tree.js**

```
import fancytree from 'jquery.fancytree';
import 'jquery.fancytree/dist/modules/jquery.fancytree.edit';
import 'jquery.fancytree/dist/modules/jquery.fancytree.filter';
import 'jquery.fancytree/dist/modules/jquery.fancytree.dnd5';
import 'jquery.fancytree/dist/modules/jquery.fancytree.glyph';
import 'jquery.fancytree/dist/modules/jquery.fancytree.table';
import 'jquery.fancytree/dist/modules/jquery.fancytree.wide';
```

I'm using RollUp, so the imports work as intended. However, I just can't find any solution to applying certain theme, i.e. bootstrap3 into my tree.
**index.html** imports

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.fancytree@2.27/dist/skin-win8/ui.fancytree.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.fancytree@2.27/dist/jquery.fancytree-all-deps.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icons.css" />
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/jquery.fancytree/dist/skin-bootstrap/ui.fancytree.css">
    <link href="./node_modules/jquery.fancytree/dist/skin-bootstrap/ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" class="skinswitcher">
```

And finally, the initialising of the FancyTree.
**Tree.js**

```
$('#explorer-tree').fancytree({
      extensions: ['dnd5', 'edit', 'glyph', 'wide'],
      glyph: {
        preset: 'bootstrap3',
        map: {
          doc: 'fa fa-file-o',
          docOpen: 'fa fa-file-o',
          checkbox: 'fa fa-square-o',
          checkboxSelected: 'fa fa-check-square-o',
          checkboxUnknown: 'fa fa-square',
          dragHelper: 'fa arrow-right',
          dropMarker: 'fa long-arrow-right',
          error: 'fa fa-warning',
          expanderClosed: 'fa fa-caret-right',
          expanderLazy: 'fa fa-angle-right',
          expanderOpen: 'fa fa-caret-down',
          folder: 'fa fa-folder-o',
          folderOpen: 'fa fa-folder-open-o',
          loading: 'fa fa-spinner fa-pulse',
        },
      },
      icon: function(event, data) {
        // if( data.node.isFolder() ) {
        //   return "glyphicon glyphicon-book";
        // }
      },
      source: [
        {title: 'project-name', key: '1',
          expanded: true},
      ],
    });
```

The tree just looks the same - default. No styling applied, no nothing. Even documentation doesn't really explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since FancyTree is made in a very isolated way, the only way to apply custom styles is to not include default ones in the first place.
I had to rewrite css files to adjust them, otherwise it just wouldn't do anything.
It would also overlap default icons with awesome4 ones if multiple css files are imported.